# What is the Linux command that encapsulates almost all of the other commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, embedded

I remember that for Linux running in embedded systems, due to size limitations, it can't pack as many commands as in ordinary workstations. So there is a do-it-all command that can mimic almost all the commands (including `ls`, `cd`, `time`, etc.), but I don't remember its name.

I just vaguely remembered something like "minibox" or something, it seems like has a "box" in its name, does anyone know what is its name?

Comment: It's called busybox.

Comment: It won't mimic `cd` though, that's not possible.

Comment: @OrangeDog: ...but it will mimic `sh`, which has `cd` as a built-in.

Comment: The one to rule them all!!!

Comment: D'oh, I was going to say `emacs`...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The most popular could be [**BusyBox**](http://www.busybox.net/), but there are also [**toolbox**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/master/toolbox/) (used by Android), [**toybox**](http://landley.net/toybox/) and maybe others.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that Busybox is an installer, not a single magic binary. At least not for Android. Busybox is an installer for tools that aren't natively on the device. It looks at the binaries already on the device and adds to them. For me, it placed the new binaries in /system/xbin/.

Comment: @Corey are you sure? its [about](http://www.busybox.net/about.html) page says *"BusyBox combines tiny versions of many common UNIX utilities into a single small executable."*.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm not as sure about iOS, but in Android you have to install BusyBox. The app itself let's you pick which version of busybox and where to install them. Mine currently says "BusyBox v1.22.1-Stericson is installed. BusyBox is installed to /system/xbin". You can look at the list of installed binaries and find them in /system/xbin/. It's not a shell, it's not an all-in-one binary, it's a bundle of binaries and an easy installer.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: The original BusyBox is the application itself. The Android app, although named BusyBox, is only an app that installs the "real" BusyBox. BusyBox itself is basicly the same, be it on Android, iOS, BSD or whatever other system. Only the installers may differ.

Comment: And the "many executables" isn't true either; busybox creates a ton of symbolic links to itself. E.g. `grep` probably is a link to busybox. The one exception is going to be `cd` as that has to be a shell built-in.

Answer (score 14):

You’re probably referring to [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/), an “all-in-one” shell.

Answer (score 3):

[BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) is designed in a fairly novel way that can be quite confusing when you start rummaging around in your /bin directories.

As [MSalters](https://superuser.com/users/73829/msalters) indicated, BusyBox is just one executable. But it depends on a symbolic link being created to that executable for every "command" in it. By knowing the symlink name it was started with, it knows to run the C function for that command.

Thus, the start of my [PuppyLinux 5.2.8 Lucid](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/Puppy526) /bin directory looks like ...

```
sh-4.1# ls -l
total 4889
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-17 10:49 [ -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-17 10:49 [[ -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-17 10:49 addgroup -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-17 10:49 adduser -> busybox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-17 10:49 ash -> busybox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2844 2011-08-17 11:04 autologinroot
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 2011-08-17 10:49 awk -> gawk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-17 10:49 basename -> busybox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 805960 2011-08-17 11:04 bash
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   6835 2011-01-21 01:29 bashbug
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-17 10:49 bbconfig -> busybox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  30200 2011-08-17 11:04 bunzip2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-17 10:49 bunzip2-BB-NOTUSED -> busybox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 busybox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  30200 2011-08-17 11:04 bzcat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-17 10:49 bzcat-BB-NOTUSED -> busybox
```

Note that most commands are symlinks to `busybox`. This includes the `ash` very minimalist shell used mostly during boot operations. Also note that the distribution author chose to include the standalone commands `bunzip2` and `bzcat` instead of using the busybox versions. The symlinks `bunzip-BB-NOTUSED` and `bzcat-BB-NOTUSED` are not really necessary but help document what's going on for just the cost of a symlink.

Note also that a directory listing that reports sizes for the target of symlinks (`ls -lL` or `ls -l --dereference`) instead of the symlink itself, will report the size of each command as the same as that of `busybox`. Thus the same list with the `-L` option shows ...

```
sh-4.1# ls -lL
total 60402
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 [
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 [[
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 addgroup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 adduser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 ash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2844 2011-08-17 11:04 autologinroot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 317880 2011-08-17 11:04 awk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 basename
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 805960 2011-08-17 11:04 bash
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   6835 2011-01-21 01:29 bashbug
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 bbconfig
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  30200 2011-08-17 11:04 bunzip2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 bunzip2-BB-NOTUSED
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 busybox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  30200 2011-08-17 11:04 bzcat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637960 2011-08-17 11:04 bzcat-BB-NOTUSED
```

The objective of BusyBox is maximum reuse of code within itself in order to minimize the memory and disk space required (i.e. the "footprint") for a common set of commands... without requiring a shell itself.

Bash and other shells accomplish the same thing. But to do so, they implement their own commandline environment. This objective is also one of the reasons for some of the very archaic syntax for many shell functionalities.

I'm currently using this "BusyBox technique" for a library of Bash functions and easier to use wrappers for various [bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). It has let me easily "extend" commands with `--help` options and fire off GUI versions when available.