# How does symlink from shutdown to systemctl work?

Tags: shell, systemctl

```
which shutdown
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/shutdown
```

I also tried `sudo which shutdown` just in case...but got the same result.

I can see that

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 13 03:38 /usr/bin/shutdown -> systemctl
```

I can also do something like (shutdown the machine in 2 hours)

```
sudo shutdown -h +120
```

But if I try something goofy like this:

```
 sudo systemctl -h +120
```

I get an error...

When I issue `shutdown` am I actually invoking the `/usr/bin/shutdown`?  If so how does the link from shutdown to systemctl actually work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

A program can know the name it was invoked as; it learns its own name by examining `argv[0]`. This allows identical executables to behave differently under different names ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1786488/432690)) or a single executable to behave differently when called via differently named symlinks ([example](https://superuser.com/a/776374/432690)).

In your case the actual `systemctl` executable knows if it's being invoked as `systemctl` or `shutdown` or whatever. It adjusts its behavior accordingly.

---

#### Additional details

The array of arguments is set by the parent process. It's a convention (not a strict requirement) that `argv[0]` is the name. The parent may or may not follow the convention. When you run `systemctl` or `shutdown` from a shell, the shell is the parent and it follows the convention; in general shells follow the convention.

An example where the convention is not followed is the behavior of `login` (and tools that try to mimic it): `login` uses a leading dash in the zeroth argument to inform a child shell it is supposed to be a login shell. Let's assume the login shell is Bash. In the shell `echo "$0"` will show you `-bash`, despite the fact the executable is named `bash`. This leading dash is *another* convention.

You can run `systemctl` with an arbitrary name. Some names are special, they change the behavior of `systemctl`, this is deliberately to support symlinks like the one you observed. In my Debian 12 these are (among others) `shutdown` and `runlevel`. You don't need to create a symlink or a copy to pass an arbitrary `argv[0]` to `systemctl`, you can use `exec -a` of Bash.

---

#### Examples of using arbitrary `argv[0]`

<sub>(The examples assume `systemctl` can be reached via `$PATH`. Supply the full pathname if needed.)</sub>

```
bash -c 'exec -a foo      systemctl'        # should behave like plain systemctl because foo is not a name that would change the behavior
bash -c 'exec -a shutdown systemctl --help' # should behave like shutdown --help
bash -c 'exec -a runlevel systemctl'        # should behave like runlevel
```

In fact you can use a symlink to `systemctl` (like your `shutdown`) and still pass an arbitrary `argv[0]`. Example:

```
bash -c 'exec -a runlevel shutdown'         # should behave like runlevel
```

---

#### Fixing your "goofy command"

Your "goofy command"

> ```
> sudo systemctl -h +120
> ```

can be fixed like this:

```
sudo bash -c 'exec -a shutdown systemctl -h +120'
```

Here the symlink named `shutdown` is not used at all (it might not exist), the executable `systemctl` is invoked directly; still it behaves like `shutdown` because we pass the right name (`shutdown`) as `argv[0]`.