# shutdown command passed with ssh or directly from a pc

Tags: linux, ssh, shutdown

from pc1 as user1, the shutdown command doesn't cause any problems, but if I try to use it remotely on pc2 as user2 using the ssh protocol, it doesn't work: it requires authentication and then it works.

```
:~$ /usr/sbin/shutdown -r 0
Failed to schedule shutdown: Interactive authentication required.

~# /usr/sbin/shutdown -r 60
Reboot scheduled for Sat 2024-01-06 11:01:36 CET, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
 
~$ ls -l /usr/sbin/shutdown lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 8 févr. 2023 /usr/sbin/shutdown -> /bin/systemctl
```

further details:

- from pc1 as user1 this command doesn't need "sudo".

How can I explain this behavior?

Comment: Do you use the same user for both operations ? I mean, `from a pc as user` and in ssh ? - `shutdown` command needs root / sudo privileges to be executed. If you are not using `sudo` and you are not `root` user, you should have specific privileges elevation like polkit or something.

Comment: Probably something like in this question: [*Why is this error: "Interactive authentication required" popping up?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650826/108618) I guess your `shutdown` is [`systemctl` in disguise](https://superuser.com/q/1823196/432690).

Comment: Why you add delay? Just exec `sudo shutdown` or `sudo init 0`

Comment: Try `sudo poweroff` or `systemctl poweroff`, although a bit brutal.

Comment: try ``ssh user2@pc2 "echo pa$sW0rd | sudo -S /usr/sbin/shutdown -r 0"''